# Copy from USB host controller to host

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, usb

I am trying to figure out where is the code that copy the Bulk URB data from the USB host controler.
I use Linux 2.6.39/ARM.
I guess it is somewhere in the (ISR) ehci or in the hcd modules, but I can't figure out where the data is actually being copied. 
I don't think DMA is being used.

BR,
Tal

Comment: I would think this would depend on the specific chip being used.  Try to find the most hardware-specific source file in the driver.  And I'd be really surprised if DMA were not utilized.

Comment: EHCI always uses DMA.

Comment: Thanks guys, i guess I was confused with the URB_NO_TRANSFER_DMA_MAP option that are needed in some driver to support DMA (DMA-aware issues).